# Why does Bjork use the term "hedging" to denote a replicating portfolio?

Tags: terminology

Reading Bjork's Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time, he keeps using the word "hedging" and "hedging portfolio" when he's talking about replicating a derivative.

Why? Is this other definition of the word "hedging" commonly used?

Comment: A hedge is an investment position intended to offset potential losses or gains that may be incurred by a companion investment. I.e. you sell derivative security and buy replicating portfolio in order to hedge the sold derivative.

Comment: This is a question about a term...not an actual concept.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, "hedging" is the term most commonly used in practice $-$ *i.e.* at trading desks, etc. $-$ for "replication" (of a derivative), while "replication" is more commonly used in academic papers. A third term, used less often than the previous two, is "synthesizing" (my impression is that "synthesizing" is normally used when a *traded*, *simple* derivative is replicated with other products, e.g. througth put-call parity you can synthesize a vanilla European call with a European put, a share and a zero-coupon bond).